# Why are servo motors geting weaker in a few minutes?

Tags: motor, servo, encoder

What I am experianceing is very weird but I will try to explane it as best as I can.

I have a simple robot arm with 4 Degrees Of Freedom (DOF). This is **not** a robotics problem but thought it would be better to write what I am doing. I am using a [Turnigy TGY-S901D](http://rcgears.co/en/all-airplane-accessories/432-turnigy-tgy-s901d-metal-gear-digital-robot-servo-13kg-014sec-58g-9000000001541.html) servo motor at each DOF. Each motor has an encoder that you send a command (via RS-485).

---

So look what happened a few days ago. I plugged it in my computer and send a command to the base motor (first DOF) one time and it worked find. Then did the same thing to the second DOF, again everything was fine. I did this for all the motors (all the DOF).

Then tried to move the first DOF again but it moved slower and not to the correct position, it needed a few degrees more. Send the same command (after I put the motor to its origin position) and it moved even slower and was even more far from the end goal. After 3-4 commands, it ended up not being able to move at all. I can hear it trying to move but with no success.

The same thing happened, after, with all the other motors. With each new command they moved slower and with a bigger error.

After that, I left the robot arm for a few days. Today I tried again to use and the first DOF does not work at all but all the others acted they way I discribed above. The first time everything worked fine and every new command made them slower.

Important NOTE: In the past I was able to use it just fine. Never had this problem. This problem appeared last week for the first time.

It is like it gets tired. Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: Power supply failure or increased friction.

Comment: Do you have a diagram? Are you extending the devices out, increasing the torque requirements on each joint?  What if you return everything to your initial conditions?

Comment: I've seen this happen with power MOSFETs stressed above their current rating, but not to the point of total failure. They start to die and have a higher and higher internal resistance. Perhaps your servos are lifting too heavy of a load?

Comment: Are you using a battery to power the servos?

Comment: @Andyaka , Power supply works like fine, just as it always does. What can have increased the friction? An internal problem in the servo? But to all at the same time?

Comment: @RDrast I have no diagram but here is one I found online http://johnny-five.io/img/images/arm-diagram.jpg . Image it is tha same without "Wrist, rotation" and the "Gripper". I am doing simple movements that don't require mush torque but in any case, the robot arm has been working fine until now. It was able to make all its movements just fine. We are just changing the software (not the firmware that the encoders have). I did try to return everything to initial conditions but no luck. I did try to move it by its old working software with no luck.

Comment: @LosFrijoles There is no load. I just was trying to make it move. And in the past it never had a problem lifting its own weight.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast No battery. I have a power supply that is plugged in the wall.

Comment: One possibility: http://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/8105/1844

Comment: My first guess would have been thermal protection but it might not have fitted all the symptoms.  The change in a 'learning' PID parameter change would account for the progressive 'degenerative' characteristics of the fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found the solution. There where 2 problems I found:

- The encoders that where in the servo use a PID that is in the
  firmware. I accidentally changed the P, I and D values in a way that
  all movement of the motors where very inefficient and trembled
  internally the motor
- Also the DOF 3 motor burned out... maybe because of the
  PID changes.

In any case, the PID are programmed correctly now and that one motor has been replaced. It is as good as new now.

Comment: I wonder, hoe would anybody guess :)

Comment: By the way, my guess was slipping encoders :)

Comment: So from the original question, "In the past I was able to use it just fine. Never had this problem. This problem appeared last week for the first time." - didn't think to mention the fact that you have altered the control gains in the servo firmware??

Comment: @Chuck the encoders have some functionality. Some are "move to absolute position" " move with velocity" "get relative position" and so on. Among these functionalities is to change the PID. It is not wrong to change the PID as long as you know what you are doing. I did not know that because most of my work with PID where in simulation environments. So I was experimenting. This is what the manufacture told me. Unfortunately I don't know everything about PID, I am still learning stuff. Next time, I will know. This is why I did not think of mentioning the PID change.